# Kill specific process in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, pid, kill-process

I'm writing a program for my school, which is supposed to terminate some processes opened by user, like for example taskmgr, or regedit etc. How to do it? I know files names, and I'm not sure how to get their PIDs.

For example, nasty student want to bypass security program which is blocking "adult" sites, or chans etc. And now I have to block executing files - only two of them - I mean taskmgr and regedit.

Comment: It would be far easier to use group policies to prevent these applications from being started in the first place.

Comment: Yes, but if make an app I'll get better mark for the end of the year. I thought about that

Comment: Then how about making an app that sets the GPO.  Then you get credit and its done right.

Comment: Just make sure your teacher doesn't have an account here...

Comment: @JoshPart fastest way to get an F- if you ask me...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to get the PID, it doesn't really get any easier than this ...

```
For Each proc As Process In Process.GetProcessesByName("taskmgr")
    proc.Kill()
Next
```